# Linux: replace a specific column if another column in same line start/end with specific character

Tags: linux, replace

I want to replace some columns conditionally in linux shell script.

Mydata is

```
ID         chr pos ver  
rs1234      1 12312 b1  
rs1245      1 21312 b1  
chr1:7576:D 1 22312 b1  
rs1002      1 34535 b1  
chr1:2434:D 1 34534 b1  
MER:1222    1 54645 b1  
rs2123      1 45645 b1
```

and I want to replace the third column with "NA" if the first column start with "MER" or end with "D".
So as the final file will be as below

```
ID         chr pos    ver  
rs1234      1 12312   b1  
rs1245      1 21312   b1  
chr1:7576:D 1 **NA**  b1  
rs1002      1 34535   b1  
chr1:2434:D 1 **NA**  b1  
MER:1222    1 **NA**  b1  
rs2123      1 45645   b1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with `awk` as follows:

```
# awk '{if(NR!=1&&($1~/^MER/||$1~/D$/)){$3="N/A"} print $0}' INPUT > OUTPUT
```

This gives the following output, using your sample data:

```
ID         chr pos ver  
rs1234      1 12312 b1  
rs1245      1 21312 b1  
chr1:7576:D 1 N/A b1
rs1002      1 34535 b1  
chr1:2434:D 1 N/A b1
MER:1222 1 N/A b1
rs2123      1 45645 b1
```

If you want to keep the formatting and your columns are fixed width, you can use a `printf` statement instead:

```
# awk '{if(NR!=1&&($1~/^MER/||$1~/D$/)){$3="N/A"} printf("%-As %Bs %Cs %Ds\n",$1,$2,$3,$4)}' INPUT > OUTPUT
```

replacing A, B, C and D with integers representing the desired column width. For example:

```
# awk '{if(NR!=1&&($1~/^MER/||$1~/D$/)){$3="N/A"} printf("%-11s  %1s  %5s %2s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4)}' INPUT > OUTPUT
```

which gives:

```
ID          chr   pos ver
rs1234       1  12312 b1
rs1245       1  21312 b1
chr1:7576:D  1    N/A b1
rs1002       1  34535 b1
chr1:2434:D  1    N/A b1
MER:1222     1    N/A b1
rs2123       1  45645 b1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with `sed`

```
sed -e 's/\(\(MER:[0-9]\+\|[0-9:]D\)\s\+[0-9]\+\s\+\)[0-9]\+\(.*\)/\1**NA**\3/g' INPUTFILE
```

which generates

```
ID         chr pos ver  
rs1234      1 12312 b1  
rs1245      1 21312 b1  
chr1:7576:D 1 **NA** b1  
rs1002      1 34535 b1  
chr1:2434:D 1 **NA** b1  
MER:1222    1 **NA** b1  
rs2123      1 45645 b1
```

But `awk` is probably the way to go here. Or perl.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using a perl one-liner:

```
perl -pe 's/^(MER:.+?|.+?:D)(\s+\d+\s+)(\d+)(.*)$/$1$2**NA**$4/' foo.txt
```

Add the -i option to perl to modify the original file directly.

**Here's a more detailed breakdown of the example above:**

You can search and replace with s/match/replace/ syntax...

```
s/^(MER:.+?|.+?:D)(\s+\d+\s+)(\d+)(.*)$/$1$2**NA**$4/
^^                                     ^            ^
```

Parenthesis are used to capture groups of matches to be used in the replacement.

```
s/^(MER:.+?|.+?:D)(\s+\d+\s+)(\d+)(.*)$/$1$2**NA**$4/
   ^_____________^^_________^^___^^__^
         $1           $2      $3   $4
```

The replacement only occurs if the regular expression matches so the first group in parenthesis determines the match in your case.  Since you want to start with `MER:` or end with `:D`, the `|` symbol is used to mean "or".

Regular expressions are a powerful way to do search and replace and are supported in many tools and languages.  It's worth finding a tutorial online to better understand this syntax.